# What does union in C++ do in this case?

Tags: c++, unions

In one of the classes that I am working I found some thing like this in the header file:

```
// Flags
union
{
    DWORD               _flags;
    struct {
        unsigned        _fVar1:1;
        unsigned        _fVar2:1; 
        unsigned        _fVar3:1; 
        unsigned        _fVar4:1;  
    };
};
```

In some of the class's member functions, I have seen `_flags` being set directly like `_flags = 3;`.
I have also seen the members in the struct being set directly, like `_fVar1 = 0` and being compared against.

I am trying to remove `_fVar1`, I am not sure what it will do to other places where `_flags` and other `_fVar#` are accessed or set. 
For instance, does setting `_flags = 3` means that `_fVar1` and `_fVar2` will be 1 and `_fVar3` and `_fVar4` will be 0? Would removing or adding to the struct means I have to make corresponding changes to codes that touches any of the other members in the union?

Comment: Technically it is UB to access the non active member of a union unlike C where the type punning is legal.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a good book that explains to you what a union is, since right now you don't seem to grasp it. Maybe start here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Comment: This is not valid C++.

Comment: The intent was probably to avoid using `#define FLAG1 0x01` etc

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, if you remove _fvar1 you have to change all places, where you use _flags.

Comment: A complication is that we have to check with the specific compiler which bits of the `unsigned` are used. The standard says *"Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined. Bit-fields are packed into some addressable allocation unit. [ Note: Bit-fields straddle allocation units on some machines and not on others. Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others. —end note ]"*. Not much to rely on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anonymous member structs (classes) are not allowed in C++, so the program is ill-formed as far as the standard is concerned.

Accessing non-active member of a union has undefined behaviour.

So in short: Whatever it does is up to the compiler.

---

Both of those are allowed in C (the former wasn't allowed until C11, the latter until C99), and by some compilers, as an extension in C++ (and as an extension in earlier versions of C). Let us assume that you use such compiler.

> For instance, does setting `_flags = 3` means that `_fVar`1 and `_fVar2` will be 1 and `_fVar3` and `_fVar4` will be 0?

That is probably the intention. However, the behaviour depends on the representation that the compiler has chosen for the bit fields.

Without making assumptions about the representation, the only sensible thing that you can use the union for is to set all flags to 0 (`_flags = 0`), or all flags to 1 (`_flags = -1`).

> Would removing or adding to the struct means I have to make corresponding changes to codes that touches any of the other members in the union?

Yes, unless the code touches all of the members equally, like the two examples above.

Comment: This is formally correct, but I'd say you should also explain how the code is intended to work.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, from @Bo Persson comments, it seems that it is possible that _fVar1 maybe the most significant bit as well, without knowing more about the compiler, right?

Comment: @tuzzer Correct. The use of the union requires assumptions about implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing very special about it. This is simply a union of an integer variable and a struct with bit fields.

Every bitfield in the struct is one bit length, so it can be used to access individual bits in the integer.